# Find zip from city and statecode

Tags: geocoding, zipcode

I want to find the zip from the city and state-code for the US only.So my problem is, for some case where city and state-code has more then **one zip-code**.(i.e. for Austin, Tx there are 78 zips) so I want to find zip of **center of the city** that can represent the whole city(work like default zip). So is there any API that can be helpful to me or any ideas..?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

[LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) can do that. In fact, the SmartyStreets homepage lookup shows the center part of the city by averaging the coordinates of all the ZIP codes for a given city. You can try out the homepage lookup yourself by going to [SmartyStreets.com](http://smartystreets.com). With the API, you'd need to create a **free** SmartyStreets account, and if you have less than 250 cities you want to look up per month it would be free.

*(Disclosure: I work at SmartyStreets.)*